# How to check control visibility in WPF app using Test Studio, Ranorex or TestComplete test tool

Tags: wpf, visibility, ui-automation, telerik-test-studio

I have a WPF application and I have to make several automation tests for GUI. I need to check if some control is visible but I don't have possibility to rebuild the application every time I change visibility option. I have a WPF Inspector and can change control options online but I'm not sure that it'll work because my test runs application every time. Could you give me a piece of advice?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? UIAutomation/Coded-UI?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, it's my first time to make automation tests. But I've heard and read about UIAutomation and Coded-UI